# How Interpret the output of propensity matching(matchIT) in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, matching, summary

Can anybody explain me Percent Balance Improvement in propensity score Matching. I am using MatchIt library in R. I ran the model successfully but I am not able to interpret the output.

```
Percent Balance Improvement:
            Mean Diff. eQQ Med eQQ Mean eQQ Max
distance     7.8916  6.1858   8.5452 44.7717
Gender      10.5178  0.0000  10.9290  0.0000
Age          9.4807 33.3333  12.4580 94.7368
Marital      6.6576  0.0000   7.0984  0.0000
```

Answer (score 2):

Ignore it. The goal of propensity score matching is to create balance between your treated and control groups. It doesn't matter whether and how much balance improved, which is what that table provides. The most useful information in the `summary()` output is the mean differences after matching. If you use `summary(..., standardize = TRUE)`, the standardized mean differences are what you want, and you should aim for them to be below .1 in absolute value. Check out the `bal.tab()` function in the `cobalt` package; it provides more straightforward output for `matchit()`.